# Why .removeClass not working?

Tags: jquery

Here is the [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/yannisdran/v6FRU/)

I found this problem during a CodeAcademy lesson.

Same goes for .addClass, .toggleClass

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#title').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('.highlighted');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$(this).removeClass('highlighted');
```

**Documentation:**

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#title').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v6FRU/1/

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, your jsfiddle example works for .removeClass, but not for .toggleClass

Answer (score 2):

Don't put dot -----> **[ . ]** before the class name remove that then it will work fine :)
Use this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#title').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
    });
});
```